# What is the standard config settings in IIS for Web Development

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, configuration, iis-7

I just enabled my IIS 7 to support my development MVC projects.
Now I am stuck as to which settings should I enable for my development.

Here's a sample snapshot of the settings I enabled.
Im not really sure if below items are correct?

[IIS Settings Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAApr.png)
[IIS Settings Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FShHI.png)

I appreciate any pro here who can advise or point me to a resource to enlighten my confusion.

Much Thanks.
Regards,
Meo

Comment: Looks fine. Did you try it?

Comment: I applied the settings base on what I think is needed, however I'm afraid I might encounter a problem which is related to IIS in the future and not on the development side.

Comment: Microsoft has explanation of each features here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/understanding-setup-in-iis But it would require experience to select what you need for a web app. If you don't have any experience, enable all features on your development machine. When deploying to another machine for testing, enable features one by one and learn from all the errors to identify which features are needed by that web app.